# Get every User Tweet MGTwitterEngine

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I just wanted to know how I could get every single tweet "tweeted" by the user by using MGTwitterEngine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at:

getUserTimelineFor:(NSString *)username sinceID:(MGTwitterEngineID)sinceID startingAtPage:(int)pageNum count:(int)count

set sinceID=0

but twitter has limits on what it will return so check the docs here: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline